# Variation with reputation for rows of file

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
4 5 6 6
1 7 5 5 
7 0 2 1
7 8 0 6
```

and I would like to produce files that have random chosen rows from this file with reputation. So the outputs can be for instance:

```
4 5 6 6
1 7 5 5 
1 7 5 5
7 8 0 6


7 8 0 6
1 7 5 5 
1 7 5 5
7 8 0 6
```

I mean that some of the rows will be in the output more times, some of the rows zero times. Is it possible to produce a list of random numbers with reputation and according to it choose rows from input? Is it possible in awk or is some other language more appropriate?

Comment: You mean _repetition_? Or _permutation_? And yes, it is possible.

Comment: I mean I have a file with 20 rows and I want to choose 20 rows in a way that some of them will be there more times and some of them zero times. I tried to generate one random number from 0 to 64 `awk 'BEGIN { srand(); printf("%d\n",rand()*65) }'` I need 65 numbers, so should I use a cycle?

Comment: there should be 64

Comment: What determines which rows should appear more often and which ones shouldn't appear at all?

Comment: random function that choose numbers like NR

Comment: So it's not a weighted distribution like your using a term like *reputation* suggests, where a higher score would mean a higher probability of being picked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ shuf -n $(wc -l < file) -r file
4 5 6 6
7 8 0 6
1 7 5 5
1 7 5 5
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I ment. What this mean please - `$(wc -l < file)` ? Is there difference in you solution and @James Brown's solution?

Comment: You're welcome. `$(...)` is telling shell to execute a command. `wc` is the command, see `man wc`. Its getting the number of lines in the input file. Look at the man page for `shuf` to see what my code will do and then read James code and then let me know if you still can't tell what they do.

Comment: The results will be similar, won't they?

Comment: Yes they will. This is just a briefer, more efficient way of doing what James awk script does.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand the concept of *reputation* but here is a way using just randomness:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM '{           # set the random seed externally
    a[NR]=$0                       # hash records to a
}
END {
    srand(seed)
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)              # 4 is the number of records to output
        print a[int(1+rand()*NR)]  # get a random array element and output it
}' file
```

An example of output:

```
7 8 0 6
7 8 0 6
7 8 0 6
1 7 5 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much and what does -v mean please?

Comment: `man gawk`: _Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins. Such variable values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program._ We set a random value from the shell (`$RANDOM`) to variable `seed` and use it as the seed for `rand()` which is a good practice, otherwise time is used and would produce the same seed within the same second. Read more about the implementation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html).

Comment: @LukášAltman you do understand that with this approach there might be no lines repeated in the output, and that all lines might be present in the output (I assume the hard-coded `4` in the loop should really be `NR`), right? I mean the output might just be a copy of the input. Is that what you wanted when you said `I have a file with 20 rows and I want to choose 20 rows in a way that some of them will be there more times and some of them zero times`?

Comment: @EdMorton I was a bit confused about the number of records needed (20? 65?) so I left the 4 there instead of `NR` to emphasize where to modify it if needed. You know, properly documenting it would've made it too clear... :D

Comment: ["That's just what they'll be expecting us to do...."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFxcJp2VQPU).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with coreutils shuf and sed, e.g.:

```
n=$(wc -l < infile)
shuf -n $n -i 1-$n -r | sed 's/$/p/' | sed -nf - infile
```

Output example:

```
4 5 6 6
4 5 6 6
1 7 5 5
1 7 5 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much